Movie about an adopted Amish girl
There was this film I watched in TV, not sure if this was a TV Movie. Language was English. The plot occurs in an Amish community. Characters include Amish parents, teenage daughter, her friend - a boy, a widower with two sons to whom the girl is betrothed. 
The girl is interested in singing. She is often scolded by her parents for singing songs that aren't approved by the Amish community. The widower's youngest son once hears her singing one of such songs. He got interested and asks her about it, since he has never seen that song in their prayer book. She tells him that the song is from a different prayer book. This lands her in trouble because the child's father hears about it and he immediately understands that she was singing an unapproved song because there is only one prayer book for their community.
Some scenes I don't remember exactly -
The girl has a guitar that was buried as a punishment by her parents?
At the end she tries to escape and go into the modern world? 
The girl was actually adopted from non-Amish couple? 

I found it - Its the 
The Shunning 

Beautiful Katie Lapp has always felt something missing in her simple Amish existence -- until a mysterious "Englisher" comes to Lancaster County looking for the baby girl she gave up for adoption 19 years ago.

